# Extracting data correctly from an array for storage

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

In the following array I'm trying to extract each clothing type and the **first** "a" and "b" values from "results" array and then store the "a" and "b" values in to the clothing type column in my database.

The outputted array structure is as follows

```
Array ( [0] =>
{
    "error": [],
    "result": {
        "shirts": {
            "a": [
                "12",
                "6",
                "6.000"
            ],
            "b": [
                "91",
                "1",
                "1.000"
            ]
        },
        "pants": {
            "a": [
                "41",
                "3",
                "3.000"
            ],
            "b": [
                "55",
                "30",
                "30.000"
            ]
        }
    }
}
)
```

So the data should go something like: Insert 12 in to the shirts type column in column a and 91 in column b, and insert 41 in to the pants type column in column a and 55 in column b.

Where am I going wrong with this foreach loop?

```
foreach($result['result'] as $clothing) {
        $query = 'UPDATE `clothing` SET `a`='.$clothing["a"].' AND SET `B`='.$clothing["a"].' WHERE `type`="'.$clothing[0].'"';
        $result = db_query($query);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: there's another level (shirts and pants), you need to point it out too directly

Comment: `Illegal string offset 'result'` based on the updated array output in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that there is an error in your JSON, with an extra `,` after the `b` array for `shirts`. Assuming you fix that, then this code shows what you get in `$clothing` (see the bottom of the answer).

```
$result = json_decode($json[0], true);
foreach($result['result'] as $clothing) {
    print_r($clothing);
}
```

As you can see, nowhere in the array is the type of clothing. So you need to change the foreach loop to access that value as well. You also have an issue with your `UPDATE` query syntax, the `AND SET` is not required. So based on that, and your requirements, your foreach loop should be:

```
foreach($result['result'] as $type => $values) {
    $query = 'UPDATE `clothing` SET `a`='.$values["a"][0].', `B`='.$values["b"][0].' WHERE `type`="'.$type.'"';
    $result = db_query($query);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 6.000
        )
    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => 91
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1.000
        )
)
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => 41
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 3.000
        )
    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => 55
            [1] => 30
            [2] => 30.000
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I realised the array output I posted was missing the initial part and yes that additional `,` was my mistake. I guess the updated output changes it to something like `$result[0]['result']` or I need to use `array_shift`?

Comment: Using `$result[0]` produces `Illegal string offset 'result'`

Comment: Based on your updated output, you would need to do `$result = json_decode($json[0], true);`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thank you! That's exactly what it needed. So decoding json first then iterating through key values.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, when you use `$clothing["a"]` youre actually getting the whole array of "a", not just the values you want.

From what I can tell the query youre trying to write is

```
foreach($result['result'] as $key => $clothing){
    $query = 'UPDATE `clothing` SET `a`='.$clothing["a"][0].', 
    `B`='.$clothing["b"][0].' WHERE `type`="'.$key.'"';
    $result = db_query($query);
}
```

So here, $key is the key of each element in your object, ie: shirts, pants

$clothing is the value of shirts and pants ie: the arrays, "a","b"

so $clothing["a"] selects "a" then $clothing["a"][0] selects the first value of "a", we use the same principle with "b". You can select the other data an "a"/"b" by changing the value in the second brackets ["a"][1], ["b"][2]

Hope this helps clear this up

Comment: thank you, but I'm getting `Undefined index: result`

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the array output, I guess that changes it to something like `$result[0]['result']` or I need to use `array_shift`?

Comment: Ah yeah just change `$result['result']` to `$result[0]['result']`

Comment: Now getting `Illegal string offset 'result'`

Comment: How are you defining $result initially? Maybe try dumping just $result and then you will see how you need to write the selectors

Comment: Thanks for all your help GiantJelly, @Nick resolved it.